# Function returns error "Not all code paths return a value"

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

When I run this function I get back an error that says `TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.`

```
async function checkAuthClaims(userId: string) {
  return admin
      .auth()
      .getUser(userId)
      .then((userRecord) => {
        console.log("User's custom claims: ", userRecord.customClaims);
        return {
          role: userRecord?.customClaims?.["role"],
          type: userRecord?.customClaims?.["type"],
        };
      });
}
```

If you know how to get rid of this error please let me know.
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What happens if `getUser(userId)` fails (in other words, the Promise doesn't resolve correctly)

Comment: @barrycarter how do i check if getUser(userId) fails?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#syntax and use the first form of the function (the one with `onRejected` in it)

Comment: @barrycarter perfect, thank you very much! If you would like to submit that as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Nah, but feel free to self-answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the first [form of the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#syntax) (the one with onRejected in it) to see if `getUser(userId)` fails (in other words, the Promise doesn't resolve correctly).